# how to hide sensitive columns postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database. I need to hide several columns (col4, col5) of a table (table1) from group_role_B. group_role_A should have permission to view (and update) all columns.

I use group roles ...the code I use (that does not work) is:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA household TO group_role_A;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA household TO group_role_B;
GRANT UPDATE, INSERT, SELECT, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA household TO group_role_A;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE household.table2, household.table3, household.table4 TO group_role_B;
GRANT SELECT (col1, col2, col3, col6, col7, col8) on table household.table1 TO group_role_B;
```

the result is: 
when group_role_B 'views' table1 the table opens with an 'aborting' message and shows no data.

Any help appreciated - I have been stuck on this for a while.

The alternative would be to use a 'view' that group_role_B could select - I had just hoped that I could avoid this by using column priviledges.

Becky

Comment: How do you "open" a table? Just SELECT the columns that you're allowed to select and it should work fine.

Comment: I am using pgadmin...and just right-clicked to 'view table' ..but when using sql's select it returns a message 'permission denied for relation household'

Comment: You can create a `view` that shows you only the columns you want to show.

Comment: yup, that is what I have done - it was just that I was trying to do it without creating views! thanks for your input. much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I'd go for the view solution.

Just read that for Oracle (and it could be that the same applies to Postgresql...)

> Only INSERT, UPDATE, and REFERENCES privileges can be granted at the column level

found this information [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/column_privileges.htm)

Comment: the query itself goes through and it suggests that it would work on this webpage: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-grant.html

Comment: Downvoted because Oracle is not PostgreSQL, and documentation is not interchangeable between the two.